# Logo Lookup API?

Tags: ios, api, logos

I'm working on an iOS application where I'd like to be able to display stores with their respective logos. I've spent a while looking for an API that does this and I can't find anything besides [XigniteLogos](https://www.xignite.com/xLogos.asmx). Unfortunately this is outside of my budget - is there a free solution available?

Comment: Might try ScrapeLogo service: http://scrapelogo.com/dead-simple-api/

Comment: I think clearbit is another good alternative

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question.

My first thought was that you could try doing a Google Image search. I know Google has a service called [Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/) which can recognize logos, so searching the other way must be possible using Google.

I did a [sample search on Google Images for "General Mills logo"](http://www.google.com/search?q=general+mills+logo&hl=en&gbv=2&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Qx-9TondHYWCtgfh0eCdBg&ved=0CCgQsAQ&biw=1737&bih=780&sei=UR-9TvraHZPqtgfDn_26Cw) (I guess I am hungry for breakfast right now) and the first result that was returned was from [SeekLogo.com](http://www.seeklogo.com/)

I am not sure what SeekLogo is, or if they have an API, but they may be exactly what you're looking for. If not, you could try a Google images search and use the first result... (Google does have [an image search AIP](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/) but... it's been *deprecated?* The [announcement of that](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html) says that the documentation / community may have solutions which are still supported...)